# SharePoint 2016 minimum hardware requirement - Azure

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, azure, resources, prerequisites

Can A series servers be used to host SharePoint 2016 in Azure?

Is it possible to host a Sharepoint farm with servers having 2 cores and 7Gb ram and 40GB HDD.

The A series servers would not have the minimum SharePoint hardware requirement which is 4 cores, 16 GB Ram and 80GB HDD.

Would we still be able to run the SharePoint farm with lesser physical resources in Azure??

For Test and Dev environments.

Sometimes on-premesis you cannot install a SharePoint server if it doesn't meet the hardware requriements.

Comment: That would probably not run, and if it does it would be dead slow. I never use less than 16GB of RAM for my on-prem SP. If search etc is a big need you would probably need more like 20 GB ram

Answer (score 0):

In the [article](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/mt779108(v=office.16).aspx), there are the minimum recommended VM sizes below. And you could use it as a reference to host SharePoint 2016 in Azure.

Windows Server AD domain controllers: Standard_D2

SQL Servers: Standard_DS4

Minority node server: Standard_D2

SharePoint servers: Standard_DS4

For more detailed information, refer to the article below.

Designing a SharePoint Server 2016 farm in Azure.

https://technet.microsoft.com/library/mt779108(v=office.16).aspx

More references:

SharePoint Server 2016 in Microsoft Azure.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt779107(v=office.16).aspx

Sizes for Windows virtual machines in Azure.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sizes